# Android Studio: RelativeLayout background color doesn't render behind the elements

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a `RelativeLayout` container with a blue background color. Inside of it I have a TextView element, but for some reason the background is rendered on top of my text and not behind it.

Here's my code:

```html
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_widget"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="80dp"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**My Bg**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00aaff"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Result:

[image]
What could be the issue here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the default text foreground color of Android .

Set any TextColor to the textview.

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

Set any color to TextView like:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="80dp"
            />
```